# Hiding lines after showing a pyplot figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using pyplot to display a line graph of up to 30 lines.  I would like to add a way to quickly show and hide individual lines on the graph.  Pyplot does have a menu where you can edit line properties to change the color or style, but its rather clunky when you want to hide lines to isolate the one you're interested in.  Ideally, I'd like to use checkboxes on the legend to show and hide lines.  (Similar to showing and hiding layers in image editors like Paint.Net)  I'm not sure if this is possible with pyplot, so I am open to other modules as long as they're somewhat easy to distribute.

Comment: Just to enrich your question, you can find this kind of behaviour (select which lines will show on the graph by clicking on the legend subtitles) in the gnuplot, e.g., http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_svg_5.0/simple.html I'm not sure how willing you are to change from pyplot to another tool (gnuplot), but if you want to keep up with python and use gnuplot there is a 'gnuplot.py' interface.

Comment: This is exactly the functionality I'm looking for.  I'll dig into it and see how well it'll work with my program.

Comment: Update: I'm giving up on gnuplot.  It wasn't working well for me.

Comment: that functionality is super easy with plotly

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you'd like, you can hook up a callback to the legend that will show/hide lines when they're clicked.  There's a simple example here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/legend_picking.html

Here's a "fancier" example that should work without needing to manually specify the relationship of the lines and legend markers (Also has a few more features).

*(Updated version in August 2019, as a response to repeated reports about this not working correctly; now it should! For the old version see [version history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31417070/revisions))*

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def main():
    x = np.arange(10)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for i in range(1, 31):
        ax.plot(x, i * x, label=r'$y={}x$'.format(i))

    ax.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1),
              ncol=2, borderaxespad=0)
    fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.55)
    fig.suptitle('Right-click to hide all\nMiddle-click to show all',
                 va='top', size='large')

    leg = interactive_legend()
    return fig, ax, leg

def interactive_legend(ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    if ax.legend_ is None:
        ax.legend()

    return InteractiveLegend(ax.get_legend())

class InteractiveLegend(object):
    def __init__(self, legend):
        self.legend = legend
        self.fig = legend.axes.figure

        self.lookup_artist, self.lookup_handle = self._build_lookups(legend)
        self._setup_connections()

        self.update()

    def _setup_connections(self):
        for artist in self.legend.texts + self.legend.legendHandles:
            artist.set_picker(10) # 10 points tolerance

        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.on_pick)
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_click)

    def _build_lookups(self, legend):
        labels = [t.get_text() for t in legend.texts]
        handles = legend.legendHandles
        label2handle = dict(zip(labels, handles))
        handle2text = dict(zip(handles, legend.texts))

        lookup_artist = {}
        lookup_handle = {}
        for artist in legend.axes.get_children():
            if artist.get_label() in labels:
                handle = label2handle[artist.get_label()]
                lookup_handle[artist] = handle
                lookup_artist[handle] = artist
                lookup_artist[handle2text[handle]] = artist

        lookup_handle.update(zip(handles, handles))
        lookup_handle.update(zip(legend.texts, handles))

        return lookup_artist, lookup_handle

    def on_pick(self, event):
        handle = event.artist
        if handle in self.lookup_artist:

            artist = self.lookup_artist[handle]
            artist.set_visible(not artist.get_visible())
            self.update()

    def on_click(self, event):
        if event.button == 3:
            visible = False
        elif event.button == 2:
            visible = True
        else:
            return

        for artist in self.lookup_artist.values():
            artist.set_visible(visible)
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        for artist in self.lookup_artist.values():
            handle = self.lookup_handle[artist]
            if artist.get_visible():
                handle.set_visible(True)
            else:
                handle.set_visible(False)
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

    def show(self):
        plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fig, ax, leg = main()
    plt.show()
```

This allows you to click on legend items to toggle their corresponding artists on/off.  For example, you can go from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the functionality I'm looking for!  I was trying to find weird workarounds like using a Tkinter GUI with checkboxes that redrew the graph every time a change was made to the selections.  This is much easier

Comment: But it's still showing the legends of the hidden plots !

Comment: While this is a super useful answer, I had to resort to the original linked code (with some modifications), because the code above broke for practically every label text that I tried other than the one specified here.

Comment: @jhin I updated the code in this example; it should now also work with other labels. Can you verify?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Great code! Note: it doesn't work anymore if we zoom on a part of the graph with the "magnifying glass" tool. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @Basj I works, you just need to **unselect** the magnifying glass tool by again clicking on the tool button (same for pan).

Comment: I think you can edit the answer to include this useful information @Stef.

Comment: @Basj I'd rather leave it as a comment as it's not related to this specific piece of code but to matplotlib in general.

Comment: For some reason this didn't want to work with a graph loaded using `pickle`, so I just saved the data used to create the graph into a `pickle` dump, then used the data to re-create the graph, and apply this code. This code works on a 'fresh' graph, but not on a graph loaded using `pickle`. This might be a matplotlib bug, I don't know. Just a note for future users. The code works perfectly fine on a fresh graph though.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the post! I extended the class above such that it can handle multiple legends - such as for example if you are using subplots. (I am sharing it here since i could not find any other example somewhere else... and it might be handy for someone else...)

```
    class InteractiveLegend(object):
 def __init__(self):

  self.legends = []
  self.figures = []
  self.lookup_artists = []
  self.lookup_handles = []

  self.host = socket.gethostname()

def add_legends(self, legend):

  self.legends.append(legend)

def init_legends(self):

    for legend in self.legends:

      self.figures.append(legend.axes.figure)

      lookup_artist, lookup_handle = self._build_lookups(legend)

      #print("init", type(lookup))

      self.lookup_artists.append(lookup_artist)
      self.lookup_handles.append(lookup_handle)

    self._setup_connections()
    self.update()

def _setup_connections(self):

    for legend in self.legends:
      for artist in legend.texts + legend.legendHandles:
          artist.set_picker(10) # 10 points tolerance

    for figs in self.figures:
      figs.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.on_pick)
      figs.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_click)

def _build_lookups(self, legend):
    labels = [t.get_text() for t in legend.texts]

    handles = legend.legendHandles
    label2handle = dict(zip(labels, handles))
    handle2text = dict(zip(handles, legend.texts))

    lookup_artist = {}
    lookup_handle = {}
    for artist in legend.axes.get_children():
        if artist.get_label() in labels:
            handle = label2handle[artist.get_label()]
            lookup_handle[artist] = handle
            lookup_artist[handle] = artist
            lookup_artist[handle2text[handle]] = artist

    lookup_handle.update(zip(handles, handles))
    lookup_handle.update(zip(legend.texts, handles))

    #print("build", type(lookup_handle))

    return lookup_artist, lookup_handle

def on_pick(self, event):

    #print event.artist
    handle = event.artist
    for lookup_artist in self.lookup_artists:
      if handle in lookup_artist:
          artist = lookup_artist[handle]
          artist.set_visible(not artist.get_visible())
          self.update()

def on_click(self, event):
    if event.button == 3:
        visible = False
    elif event.button == 2:
        visible = True
    else:
        return

    for lookup_artist in self.lookup_artists:
      for artist in lookup_artist.values():
          artist.set_visible(visible)
    self.update()

def update(self):
    for idx, lookup_artist in enumerate(self.lookup_artists):
      for artist in lookup_artist.values():
          handle = self.lookup_handles[idx][artist]
          if artist.get_visible():
              handle.set_visible(True)
          else:
              handle.set_visible(False)
      self.figures[idx].canvas.draw()

def show(self):
    plt.show()
```

use it as follow:

```
leg1 = ax1.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), ncol=2, borderaxespad=0)
leg2 = ax2.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), ncol=2, borderaxespad=0)
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.7)

interactive_legend = InteractiveLegend()

interactive_legend.add_legends(leg1)
interactive_legend.add_legends(leg2)
interactive_legend.init_legends()
interactive_legend.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @JoeKington's answer, here is what I use (a slightly modified version, that doesn't require `ax, fig` but can work directly with `plt.plot(...)`; also `plt.legend()` is kept outside out the scope of the main object):

Ready-to-use example `pltinteractivelegend.py`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class InteractiveLegend(object):
    def __init__(self, legend=None):
        if legend == None:
            legend = plt.gca().get_legend()
        self.legend = legend
        self.fig = legend.axes.figure
        self.lookup_artist, self.lookup_handle = self._build_lookups(legend)
        self._setup_connections()
        self.update()
    def _setup_connections(self):
        for artist in self.legend.texts + self.legend.legendHandles:
            artist.set_picker(10) # 10 points tolerance
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.on_pick)
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_click)
    def _build_lookups(self, legend):
        labels = [t.get_text() for t in legend.texts]
        handles = legend.legendHandles
        label2handle = dict(zip(labels, handles))
        handle2text = dict(zip(handles, legend.texts))
        lookup_artist = {}
        lookup_handle = {}
        for artist in legend.axes.get_children():
            if artist.get_label() in labels:
                handle = label2handle[artist.get_label()]
                lookup_handle[artist] = handle
                lookup_artist[handle] = artist
                lookup_artist[handle2text[handle]] = artist
        lookup_handle.update(zip(handles, handles))
        lookup_handle.update(zip(legend.texts, handles))
        return lookup_artist, lookup_handle
    def on_pick(self, event):
        handle = event.artist
        if handle in self.lookup_artist:
            artist = self.lookup_artist[handle]
            artist.set_visible(not artist.get_visible())
            self.update()
    def on_click(self, event):
        if event.button == 3:
            visible = False
        elif event.button == 2:
            visible = True
        else:
            return
        for artist in self.lookup_artist.values():
            artist.set_visible(visible)
        self.update()
    def update(self):
        for artist in self.lookup_artist.values():
            handle = self.lookup_handle[artist]
            if artist.get_visible():
                handle.set_visible(True)
            else:
                handle.set_visible(False)
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(20):
        plt.plot(np.random.randn(1000), label=i)
    plt.legend()    
    leg = InteractiveLegend()
    plt.show()
```

Usage as a library:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pltinteractivelegend

for i in range(20):
    plt.plot(np.random.randn(1000), label=i)
plt.legend()    
leg = pltinteractivelegend.InteractiveLegend()  # mandatory: keep the object with leg = ...; else it won't work
plt.show()
```