# Hiding lines after plotting in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to implement the solution presented by @Joe Kington in the following stack overflow thread:

[Hiding lines after showing a pyplot figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410043/hiding-lines-after-showing-a-pyplot-figure)

I have 16 lines I am trying to plot with this method, each of which have their own unique color and label. While @Joe Kington's solution works fine to get the plot to display, I cannot transfer his interactive method to my code with the interactive functionality of clicking on the legend entries to hide a line. That is, my code plots my data without error but there is no interactive functionality occurring.

I have tried:

- setting the unique labels to be raw strings and regular strings
- setting up every line to plot to be iterated over as in @Joe Kington's solution
- using smaller legend labels
- rearranging blocks of my code in the event that the functions defined in @Joe Kington's solution are out of scope

@Joe Kington's solution is below, which works fine:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def main():
    x = np.arange(10)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for i in range(1, 31):
        ax.plot(x, i * x, label=r'$y={}x$'.format(i))

    ax.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1),
              ncol=2, borderaxespad=0)
    fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.55)
    fig.suptitle('Right-click to hide all\nMiddle-click to show all',
                 va='top', size='large')

    leg = interactive_legend()
    return fig, ax, leg

def interactive_legend(ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    if ax.legend_ is None:
        ax.legend()

    return InteractiveLegend(ax.get_legend())

class InteractiveLegend(object):
    def __init__(self, legend):
        self.legend = legend
        self.fig = legend.axes.figure

        self.lookup_artist, self.lookup_handle = self._build_lookups(legend)
        self._setup_connections()

        self.update()

    def _setup_connections(self):
        for artist in self.legend.texts + self.legend.legendHandles:
            artist.set_picker(10) # 10 points tolerance

        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.on_pick)
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_click)

    def _build_lookups(self, legend):
        labels = [t.get_text() for t in legend.texts]
        handles = legend.legendHandles
        label2handle = dict(zip(labels, handles))
        handle2text = dict(zip(handles, legend.texts))

        lookup_artist = {}
        lookup_handle = {}
        for artist in legend.axes.get_children():
            if artist.get_label() in labels:
                handle = label2handle[artist.get_label()]
                lookup_handle[artist] = handle
                lookup_artist[handle] = artist
                lookup_artist[handle2text[handle]] = artist

        lookup_handle.update(zip(handles, handles))
        lookup_handle.update(zip(legend.texts, handles))

        return lookup_artist, lookup_handle

    def on_pick(self, event):
        handle = event.artist
        if handle in self.lookup_artist:

            artist = self.lookup_artist[handle]
            artist.set_visible(not artist.get_visible())
            self.update()

    def on_click(self, event):
        if event.button == 3:
            visible = False
        elif event.button == 2:
            visible = True
        else:
            return

        for artist in self.lookup_artist.values():
            artist.set_visible(visible)
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        for artist in self.lookup_artist.values():
            handle = self.lookup_handle[artist]
            if artist.get_visible():
                handle.set_visible(True)
            else:
                handle.set_visible(False)
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

    def show(self):
        plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fig, ax, leg = main()
    plt.show()
```

Here is a snippet of my code that isn't working that is defined in a module plotting in a function called main() (I have other modifications I need to make such as changing axis labels, unique colors, etc.):
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
def main(t,n,timeSpan):

    colors = ['blue','red','green','black','magenta','teal','orange','chartreuse','purple','sienna','goldenrod','lightgray','olive','cyan','maroon','pink']
    labels = [r'foo1',r'bar2',r'foo3',r'bar4',r'foo5',r'bar6',r'foo7',r'bar8',r'foo9',r'bar10',r'foo11',r'bar12',r'foo13',r'bar14',r'foo15',r'bar16']

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))
    for i in range(0, len(colors)):
        ax.plot(t, n[:,i], color = colors[i], label = labels[i])

    ax.set_xlabel('x label')
    ax.set_ylabel('y label')
    ax.set_xlim([0,timeSpan])
    ax.set_ylim([0,110])
    ax.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1),
              ncol=2, borderaxespad=0)
    fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.55)
    fig.suptitle('Title\n(Right-click to hide all\nMiddle-click to show all)',
                     va='top', size='large')

    leg = interactive_legend()
    plt.show()

def interactive_legend(ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    if ax.legend_ is None:
        ax.legend()

    return InteractiveLegend(ax.get_legend())

class InteractiveLegend(object):
    def __init__(self, legend):
        self.legend = legend
        self.fig = legend.axes.figure

        self.lookup_artist, self.lookup_handle = self._build_lookups(legend)
        self._setup_connections()

        self.update()

    def _setup_connections(self):
        for artist in self.legend.texts + self.legend.legendHandles:
            artist.set_picker(10) # 10 points tolerance

        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.on_pick)
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_click)

    def _build_lookups(self, legend):
        labels = [t.get_text() for t in legend.texts]
        handles = legend.legendHandles
        label2handle = dict(zip(labels, handles))
        handle2text = dict(zip(handles, legend.texts))

        lookup_artist = {}
        lookup_handle = {}
        for artist in legend.axes.get_children():
            if artist.get_label() in labels:
                handle = label2handle[artist.get_label()]
                lookup_handle[artist] = handle
                lookup_artist[handle] = artist
                lookup_artist[handle2text[handle]] = artist

        lookup_handle.update(zip(handles, handles))
        lookup_handle.update(zip(legend.texts, handles))

        return lookup_artist, lookup_handle

    def on_pick(self, event):
        handle = event.artist
        if handle in self.lookup_artist:

            artist = self.lookup_artist[handle]
            artist.set_visible(not artist.get_visible())
            self.update()

    def on_click(self, event):
        if event.button == 3:
            visible = False
        elif event.button == 2:
            visible = True
        else:
            return

        for artist in self.lookup_artist.values():
            artist.set_visible(visible)
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        for artist in self.lookup_artist.values():
            handle = self.lookup_handle[artist]
            if artist.get_visible():
                handle.set_visible(True)
            else:
                handle.set_visible(False)
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

    def show(self):
        plt.show()

t = np.arange(1000)
n = np.zeros([1000,16])
for i in range(0, 1000):
    for j in range(0, 16):
        n[i][j] = t[i] * j
timeSpan = 1000

# if __name__ == "__main__":
#     main(t,n,timeSpan)

colors = ['blue','red','green','black','magenta','teal','orange','chartreuse','purple','sienna','goldenrod','lightgray','olive','cyan','maroon','pink']
labels = [r'foo1',r'bar2',r'foo3',r'bar4',r'foo5',r'bar6',r'foo7',r'bar8',r'foo9',r'bar10',r'foo11',r'bar12',r'foo13',r'bar14',r'foo15',r'bar16']


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))
for i in range(0, len(colors)):
    ax.plot(t, n[:,i], color = colors[i], label = labels[i])

ax.set_xlabel('x label')
ax.set_ylabel('y label')
ax.set_xlim([0,timeSpan])
ax.set_ylim([0,110])
ax.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1),
          ncol=2, borderaxespad=0)
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.55)
fig.suptitle('Title\n(Right-click to hide all\nMiddle-click to show all)',
                  va='top', size='large')

leg = interactive_legend()
plt.show()
```

I have determined that when I leave the code as is it works, but when I comment out lines 113-131 and call main() from lines 111 and 112 insead, it no longer works. Is this a scope issue? Not sure why the way I am calling the interactive_legend() function determines whether it works or not.

Comment: I'm a bit lost here. Is the code you are showing working for you or not? If it is working, one would need to see the code (a [mcve]) that is not working instead. If it is not working, we need a more detailed description of what's wrong, also including potential errors, your way of running the code, system and library (-versions).

Comment: Ok, so I updated that [linked example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31417070/4124317). Could you test if it is now working for you?

Comment: Thank you for going back and editing that! So it looks like while your fix was able to correct the issue with @Joe Kington's original code, but I still have the issue with my code. I will edit my question and be more descriptive of my issue, my apologies for not being clear at first.

Comment: I suppose the issue is the same still. But I might be wrong. For that please provide an entire code that can be copied and run as it is, such that we both see exactly the same thing and one can hence analyse where it fails. Again see [mcve].

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you again for all of the attention and help. I have provided an entire code. I found out more specifically where my issue is coming from, as it may seem to be a scope issue since it works depending on how I call the interactive_legend() function, but I am not sure why or what is going on with that.

Comment: It's about garbage collection. A class instance that has no reference to it will be removed from memory. You may do just as in the corrected example and store a reference. (That's why I edited that example in the first place, right?)