# How to autoscaled graphs with picking legend (matplotlib)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, autoscaling

I am working on a picking legend with matplotlib. The goal is to hide and shows curves, by clicking on the legend. I found this solution ([Hiding lines after showing a pyplot figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410043/hiding-lines-after-showing-a-pyplot-figure)), which works very well.

I want improve this code to adapt automatically the axis after each clic on the legend. I don't know if it is possible. Do you have any hint?

Their is an example of what I want on the images below. First of all, the Image 1 represents the graph. Then after clicking on the legend 5*sin(x), the orange curve disappears as expected (Image 2). On the Image 2, the y-axis is not optimized. The result expected is on the Image 3.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A4QD.png)

Thank you very much,

Comment: post you code or a sample that you tried it so we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a call to the relim method with the visible_only flag set to True and updating the axis should perform the way you want. This will need to be added to your on_click/update method.

```
# Where ax2 is a reference to your second axis
ax2.relim(visible_only=True)  # Ignore the line you've hidden when rescaling.
ax2.autoscale_view()  # assuming the axis has not been altered by set_xlim etc.
```