# Show/hide a plot in a multiplot display with a few clicks

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm displaying 20 different series on the same graph (it's important they are on a single plot):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
for i in range(20):
    plt.plot(np.random.randn(1000), label=i)  # random data here, but real data in my code
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**Question: how to be able to show/hide a particular series with a simple click?**

Is there a way to make the legend clickable, such that a click on the legend shows/hides a particular series?

Example: you have 20 series, and you want to display only #4, #5 together. Then you want to display only #13 and #7, just with a few clicks, **without manually modifying the Python code**.

[image]

---

Note: The answers [Hiding lines after showing a pyplot figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410043/hiding-lines-after-showing-a-pyplot-figure) are useful, but it's not very handy to use. Is there a way to do this (maybe thanks to a package?) in a few lines only?

Comment: If you want a lot of interactivity "out of the box", the bokeh and plotly libraries might be interesting. They run in Python, but create an interactive webpage (default they automatically open a browser window; they can also be part of a Jupyter notebook).

Comment: See e.g. https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/legends.html

Comment: @JohanC It would be interesting to post this information (with a small sample code) as an answer. It really adds something new here that is not present in the duplicate's answers. Feel free to vote to reopen this question to be able to post it.