# Checkboxes to select plots in realtime live matplotlib (interactive) display

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, interactive

Is there a `matplotlib` built-in way to display **checkboxes** along the legend, allowing the user to select/unselect some of the 3 curves in a realtime live plotting? (I currently refresh data with `set_ydata`, but I can change this if needed)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import threading, time

def visualization_thread():
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        l1, *_ = ax.plot(y1, color='r', label="1")
        l2, *_ = ax.plot(y2, color='g', label="2")
        l3, *_ = ax.plot(y3, color='b', label="3")
        fig.show()
        fig.legend()
        fig.canvas.flush_events()
        while True:
            l1.set_ydata(y1)
            l2.set_ydata(y2)
            l3.set_ydata(y3)
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()
            fig.canvas.flush_events()
            plt.pause(0.020)

def data_thread():
    global y1, y2, y3
    while True:
        y1 = np.random.rand(100)
        y2 = np.random.rand(100)
        y3 = np.random.rand(100)
        time.sleep(0.020)

threading.Thread(target=data_thread).start()
threading.Thread(target=visualization_thread).start()
```

[image]

Comment: Not a checkbox, but this might do what you want: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/event_handling/legend_picking.html#sphx-glr-gallery-event-handling-legend-picking-py

Comment: Thanks @jared! I have used something very similar a few years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64752658/1422096, but I was curious if there is an easier built-in way nowadays with simple checkboxes.

Comment: You could probably try to use something like CheckButtons: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/check_buttons.html